# Capacitor Write Files to Download Folder

Tags: vue.js, capacitor

I am using ionic capacitor to convert a web app to an android application. In my application I have csv download feature which was using this code to download csv file

```
   const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "text/csv" });
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   const link = document.createElement("a");
   link.href = url;
   const fileName = this.fileName + "_" + date + ".csv";
   link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
```

This doesn't work on capacitor so I used their `Filesystem` plugin to write the file on to storage. The issue is that using the `FilesystemDirectory` I can save files to `Cache`, `Data`, `Documents`, `External` and `ExternalStorage`. It works but it's not convenient. How can I move file to `Downloads` folder ?

Here is my full code

```
 async fetchCsvFromApi(payloadData) {
      const info = await Device.getInfo();
      return await this.$store
        .dispatch("exportCsv/fetchCsv", payloadData)
        .then(response => {
          var today = new Date();
          var date =
            today.getFullYear() +
            "-" +
            (today.getMonth() + 1) +
            "-" +
            today.getDate();
          const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "text/csv" });
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          const fileName = this.fileName + "_" + date + ".csv";
          link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
          if(info && ['android', 'ios'].includes(info.platform)){ 
            this.fileWrite(response.data, fileName)
          }else{
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
          this.$toast.error(error.response.data.message);
        });
    },
    async fileWrite(data, fileName) {
      try {
        const result = await Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: fileName,
          data: data,
          directory: FilesystemDirectory.External,
          encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
        })
        console.log('Wrote file', result);
      } catch(e) {
        console.error('Unable to write file', e);
      }
    },
```

I am using this on a Vue.js project.

Comment: Totally agree with you. It's pretty weird that the Downloads directory is not part of the common directories.

Answer (score 2):

Specify **Download** directory before filename and **FilesystemDirectory.ExternalStorage** as directory.
Following code works for me:

```
const fileName = `Download/file.pdf`;
await Filesystem.writeFile({
  path: fileName,
  data: data, // your data to write (ex. base64)
  directory: FilesystemDirectory.External
});
```

Comment: Maybe just to add, you can not use the path to the file in download folder to display your file, but have to use the read functionality to use the file again.

`Filesystem.readFile({
      path: "Download/file.pdf",
      directory: FilesystemDirectory.ExternalStorage,
 })`